# Using MediaPlayer in WPF

Tags: wpf

I try to add a mediaplayer to my WPF application but don't get any sound. I have added a wav file, as seen below.

```
//option 1
            string soundname = "test.Wav";
            MediaPlayer soundtrack = new MediaPlayer();
            soundtrack.Open(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Assets/sounds/" + soundname));
            soundtrack.Play();

            //option 2
            MediaPlayer Sound1 = new MediaPlayer();
            Sound1.Open(new Uri(@"Assets/sounds/test.Wav"));
            Sound1.Play();
```

The first option (which is what I really want) doesn't crash the program but I hear no sound (and no, the computer sound is not muted...). The second one, which I got from MSDN, crashes my program, saying an instance of the object can't be found.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the "Build Action" set as in the properties of the sound file in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with setting your Build Action on your wav file properties to `Content` and your Copy to Output Directory to `Copy Always`, then try the following.

```
 MediaPlayer Sound1 = new MediaPlayer();
 Uri uri = new Uri(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Assets\Sounds\test.wav", UriKind.Absolute);
 Sound1.Open(uri);
 Sound1.Play();
```

This will grab the file from the applications directory.

Also note the MediaPlayer will experience issues if you try and execute it before rendering is complete. So if you are trying this in WPF in let's say `public MainWindow()` it won't play.

Comment: Thanks, however I am trying to use the MediaPlayer. The reason why is that I want to be able to run a soundtrack and sound effects at once and SoundPlayer only plays one sound at a time. I looked at Content etc and they were correct (as you set them).

Comment: @petter I got you. I edited my answer, it should help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was indeed most helpful! :D